# Jquery $.post() gives same page in HTML back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I have written a page so i can create a friendship between users. But my Problem is that jquery wont post the parameters.

I need some help, to fix that issue.

My Code:

```
//currentURL -> e.g: firstname.lastname

$('#friendRequestButton').on("click",function(e){
     if(currentURL != "" && typeof(currentURL) != "undefined"){

          $.post("sendFriendRequest.php",{user1:$.cookie("user-id"),user2:currentURL})
              .done(function(data) {
                   console.log(data); // Here I get the same page(in HTML-format).. as result in the console.
              });
              //$('#friendRequestButton').attr("disabled","true");

     }

});
```

If you need more details, let me know.
My PHP-Code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['user1']) && isset($_POST['user2'])){

        $user1 = $_POST['user1'];
        $user2 = $_POST['user2']
        die("OK!");
    }else {
        die("NOO!");
    }
?>
```

**EDIT:** I changed the way you mentioned with `e.preventDefault();`

```
<?php
            $friends = false;
            if(!$friends){
                ?>

                <center>
                    <button class="submit" id="friendRequestButton">Ask for friendship</button>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button>Send Message!</button>
                </center>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(e){
                        $('#friendRequestButton').on("click",function(e){
                        console.log(e.target);
                        e.preventDefault();
                            if(currentURL != "" && typeof(currentURL) != "undefined" && $.cookie("user-id") != "" && typeof($.cookie("user-id")) != "undefined"){

                                $.post("sendFriendRequest.php",{user1:$.cookie("user-id"), user2:currentURL},function(data){
                                        console.log(data);
                                }
                                );
                                //$('#friendRequestButton').attr("disabled","true");

                            }else {
                                console.log("NOOOOO");   
                            }

                        });
                    });



                </script>
            <?php
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the html it is a guess, but judging by the name of your element you are using a button. Probably that button submits the form the "normal" way, causing your page to reload and you to not see the results of your ajax call.

If that is the case, you need to prevent the default event for the button press (submitting the form in this case):

```
$('#friendRequestButton').on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // the rest of your code
```

Comment: Sorry, but the page doesn't reload and yes it's a button. And event that "preventing" wont work.

Comment: @Fr0zenOfficial Are you sure you are calling the correct file in your ajax request?

Comment: The file is on the highest folder, and the page with jquery is 3 folders deeper. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: @Fr0zenOfficial You will see in the console easily enough if the right file is called. But if it is located in the root of the web-server, you should use the absolute path to make sure: `/sendFriendRequest.php`. Is the "ask for friendship" code section part of a loop? If it is you will have problems with duplicate ID's.

Comment: 1st: No loop. 2nd: it's in a folder within the root, there i have written my `sendFriendRequest.php` page and 3 folders deeper I have a `profile.php` where the request-button is.

Answer (score 0):

use your ajax request like this-

$.post("sendFriendRequest.php",{user1:$.cookie("user-id"),user2:currentURL}),function(data){
              console.log(data);
           });

Comment: same result as always.

Comment: it has always a value. First time you login the cookie will be set.

Answer (score 0):

I found the ISSUE:

I'm SOOOO Stupid:

I have written the filename like this: `sendFriendRequest..php` (two dots)
It should be: `sendFriendRequest.php`
So thanks everyone for helping!! :D